# attribute equals selector is not recognized in safari 5.1.7

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari

I am using below code to find particular row with it's attribute. this is not working in safari 5.1.7 brower,It throws the error **Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #groups tr[data-group_mandatory="true"**

```
$('#groups tr[data-group_mandatory="true"').each(function(){        

        // Some Logic here.         
    });
```

Comment: should be `$('#groups tr[data-group_mandatory="true"]')`

Comment: `'#groups tr[data-group_mandatory="true"]'` -- missing `]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing closing square bracket, please correct it like below :

```
$('#groups tr[data-group_mandatory="true"]')
                                         ^-- bracket was missing
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have carefully looked at error that you have got. You have typo in your code. you have not closed square bracket for name-value selector:

```
$('#groups tr[data-group_mandatory=true]').each(function(){        

    // Some Logic here.         
});
```